# Understanding a simple online contract which seems not functional

Tags: security, contract-debugging

I am writing to understand the functionality of this contract (https://etherscan.io/address/0x1f14b77e9f4844889fa63bc1e5180c8b90ec18db), this does not look even "functional" to me.

Here is the decompiled output this contract with JEB3:

```
contract DecompiledContract {
    function start() {
        *0x40 = 0x60;
        var0 = msg.data.length;

        if(var0 != 0x0) {
            var0 = (uint256)$msg.sig;

            if(var0 == 0x41c0e1b5) {
                kill();
            }

            if(var0 == 0xe5225381) {
                collect();
            }
        }

        if($msg.value > 0x0) {
            var2 = msg.sender;
            uint256* var6 = *0x40;
            *var6 = $msg.value;
            emit Deposit(*0x40, var6 + 1 - *0x40);
        }

        stop();
    }

    function kill() public payable {
        __impl_kill();
        stop();
    }

    function collect() public payable {
        __impl_collect();
        stop();
    }

   function __impl_kill() private {
        var1 = storage[0x0];
        int256 var0 = var1;
        var1 = msg.sender;

        if((address(var0)) == (address(msg.sender))) {
            var1 = storage[0x0];
            suicide(address(var1));
        }
    }

    function __impl_collect() private {
        var1 = storage[0x0];
        int256 var0 = var1;
        var1 = msg.sender;

        if((address(var0)) == (address(msg.sender))) {
            var1 = storage[0x0];
            var2 = address(this);
            var2 = balance(address(var2));
            uint256 var5 = *0x40;
            var4 = call(0x0, address(var1), var2, var5, *0x40 - var5, var5, 0x0);
        }
    }

}
```

It seems to me that this contract is performing some fund collection (like shown in the `fallback` function), and when the owner calls the `collect` function, the fund will all be transferred to the owner.

However, the major confusion is that there is no `deposit` operation. I tried to search for EVM opcode `sstore` in the disassembled output, but just cannot find one. Without a `sstore`, how can it deposit to the global storage? Am I missed anything here?